# POSTGRESQL: how to filter to produce a query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a text book question; List the ids and names of people who have received the grade an A for every class for the tables;

Student {studentID, name}
Grade {studentID, courseName, grade}

and I am not sure how to filter out the grades so that i only show the A students.
So far i have the solution

```
SELECT Student.studentID, Student.name
FROM Student, Grade
WHERE Student.studentID = Grade.StudentID AND
Grade.grade = 'A' AND
Grade.grade != 'B' AND
Grade.grade != 'C' AND
Grade.grade != 'D' AND
Grade.grade != 'F';
```

Is there a cleaner way I can filter this. It just seems a bit tedious that I write the not equals 4 times.

Comment: You mean students with grade A in all subjects , also Course table is not used in FROM class

Comment: sorry that was a mistake, i don't know why i wrote Course instead of Grade

Comment: If `grade` is equal to 'A' it must be different to anything else. You don't need the `!=` conditions

Comment: but a student does more than 1 class. what if a student did one class and got an A and did another and got a F. If i only had grade = A this particular student would show up, even though they got a F

Comment: Are you and 'tristiana' the same person? http://stackoverflow.com/q/26326242/398670 . Or two students with the same homework? (Please always tell us when it's a homework question. You'll still get an answer, but generally get more explanation.)

Answer (score 2):

```
select studentid, s.name
from
    student s
    inner join
    grade g using (studentid)
group by studentid, s.name
having bool_and(g.grade = 'A')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `NOT EXISTS` class. we are getting all students which didn't get A and filtering them out.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Student.studentID, Student.name
FROM  Student 
JOIN Grade 
ON Student.studentId = Grade.studentId
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Grade G
                   WHERE G.grade !='A'
                   and G.studentID = Student.studentID
                  )
```

Comment: This query will give you all students that have no grades at all.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko, good point, i added join in the main select to handle that.