# PostgreSQL. how to make a query that shows pairs from the same column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables

```
Students{sId, name}
Class{cId, cName} and 
Enrollment{sId, cId, semester}
```

A student can enroll in multiple classes. I need to produce a query that displays all the pairs of students (their names and ids )who have completed one or more of the same classes in the same semester. I'm not really sure what I am to SELECT to display because I need to display in a format that shows the pairs

I started by doing the joins and came up with this

```
FROM Students s
INNER JOIN Enrollment e
ON s.sId = e.sId
INNER JOIN Class c
ON c.cId = e.sId
```

Then I am not sure what to do.. If someone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated. I am very new to SQL and am even struggling to find some keywords to google.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get? I'm afraid the question isn't too clear, at least not to me.

Comment: It sounds like this question (homework?) wants you to perform a *self-join*.

Comment: Are you and 'serialchiller' the same person? http://stackoverflow.com/q/26325247/398670 . Or two students with the same homework? (Please always tell us when it's a homework question. You'll still get an answer, but generally get more explanation.)

Comment: Not sure if serial chiller and I know each other, but this isn't a homework question, it may be from the same textbook?